# How to stabilize the header

Tags: css, jsf-2

My web application header contain the a text on center and an ajax status on the right side.

Each time the user will activate the ajax the header text will jump to the left

```
<h:outputText value="${messages.HEADER}"/>
<p:ajaxStatus id="ajax-StatusPanel" onsuccess="" style="float: right;margin-top: -5px;margin-right:10px;">                                                                     
    <f:facet name="start">                                                                                                                 
        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />                                                                        
    </f:facet>                                                                                                                             
    <f:facet name="complete">                                                                                                              
        <h:outputText value=""/>                                                                                
    </f:facet>                                                                                                                             
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

Header text css:

```
.pe-layout-inner-north > .pe-layout-pane-content {
    background-color: #5080C0;
    border:1px solid #222222;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display: block;
}
```

How can I permanently set the header on the center?

Thanks

Comment: Is the width static or dynamic?

Comment: sorry i don't understand your question? css is not my strong side

Comment: Is it a set width, or will it change?

Comment: the text width will not change and also the image

Comment: So set a width to the element, and set `margin:0 auto;` rather than trying to use `text-align:center;` on its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution - using h:panelGrid:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="mainHeader" style="margin:0px auto;">
    <h:outputText value="${dy_messages.DYE_HEADER}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
<p:ajaxStatus id="ajax-StatusPanel" onsuccess="" style="float: right;margin-right:10px;margin-top: -32px">                                                                     
    <f:facet name="start">                                                                                                                 
        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />                                                                        
    </f:facet>                                                                                                                             
    <f:facet name="complete">                                                                                                              
        <h:outputText value=""/>                                                                                
    </f:facet>
```

Thanks